# Factory Pattern, selecting by Property

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

I have a (growing) list of Data-Generators. The generator that I need is created by a factory class. The generators all implement a common Interface, which includes among other things a static string `name`.

What I would like to do: Call the factory.Create method with a string parameter for the above mentioned name. The create method finds the generator with this name and returns a new instance of said generator.

Bonus in my opinion of this way to do it: I only have to add new generator classes without having to edit the factory.

Question:

1. Is this a good way to handle this problem?
2. How can I find all generators? Reflection over every implementation of the interface/every member of the namespace (unique for the generators + their interface)?
3. Is it correct to call this way of working a factory, or is this some different pattern?

In the end I would call the factory like this (simplified):

```
//Caller
public DataModel GetData2()
{
    var generator = new DataFactory().Create("Gen.2");
    return generator.GetData();
}

//Factory
public class DataFactory
{
    public AbstractDataGenerator Create(string type)
    {
        //Here the magic happens to find all implementations of IDataGenerator
        var allGenerators = GetImplementations();
        var generator = allGenerators.FirstOrDefault(f => f.name == type);
        if (generator != null)
            return (AbstractDataGenerator)Activator.CreateInstance(generator);
        else
            return null;
    }
}

//Interface
public abstract class AbstractDataGenerator
{
    public static string name;
    public abstract DataModel GetData();
}

//Data-Generators
public class DataGen1 : AbstractDataGenerator
{
    public static string name = "Gen.1";
    public DataModel GetData()
    {
        return new DataModel("1");
    }
}
public class DataGen2 : AbstractDataGenerator
{
    public static string name = "Gen.2";
    public DataModel GetData()
    {
        return new DataModel("2");
    }
}
```

Should the magic `GetImplementations()` in the factory be done via Reflection or somehow different? Should I use a completely different approach?

Since answers refer to IoC and DI: This project uses NInject already, so it would be available.
Switched from interface to abstract class.

Comment: One issue I have found with this approach is that in order to get the "Name" property of the generator you _need an instance of the object_.

Comment: That's why I made the property static. This should remove the need for an instance, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Interfaces cannot have static members..

Comment: @stuartd Good Comment. I could use an abstract class instead of the Interface. - Edit: Done.

Comment: @MilConDoin using a `static` field/property like that on your `abstract` class would cause it to be overridden every time you set it on. You may need to rethink using `static` field

Comment: @MilConDoin - Is the question answered or do you still have any other question?

Comment: @GiladGreen I'm currently working on getting running code. Also trying Trevor's approach by utilizing the available NInject. When everything works good enough, I'll give my accepted mark :)

Comment: @MilConDoin - ah no problem. Was asking just to see if you need any other help with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a good way to handle this problem?

Having a factory to get an instance of the logic class you need by some key - I believe it is a good way. It is a pattern that I use a lot myself. About the way you have your key - I'd prefer to not have it as a `static` member (regardless to the fact that interfaces can't have static members) but just as a `property` and to add a base class to the `IDataGenerator`. That base class will have a constructor that will get the `name` - That way each new `DataGenerator` you create will have to set it and you wont forget.

---

About having the `name` as a `string` - I personally prefer having it "strongly typed". What I mean is that if I pass `Gen . 2` instead of `Gen.2` with strings I will discover this problem only in runtime. Possible other ways (if you want, because a simple string is fine too - a matter of taste):

- Replace strings with an `enum`
- Have a static class with static readonly strings for all your values - then in your code use those values. You get the benifits of the intellisense and of not getting the string wrong but better than enum - you can just still pass strings that are not in the "list" so you can add new ones as add-ons.
- Have a `RequestGenerator` object, with each `Generator` being `IDataGenerator<TGeneratorRequest>`. This might be an overkill but if you have also extra information you need for the creating of a `DataGenerator` which differs between them then consider it .

> How can I find all generators? Reflection over every implementation of the interface/every member of the namespace (unique for the generators + their interface)?

Yes, reflection can be a good way to do so. However, I would suggest to read into `Dependency Injection` and `IoC Containers` like `Castle Windsor` for example. There are things out there that already implement it for you, so why to re-invent the wheel :)

`DI` is a life changer concept in my opinion

> Is it correct to call this way of working a factory, or is this some different pattern?

Yap. It is a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

> Should the magic GetImplementations() in the factory be done via Reflection or somehow different?

See answer for question 2

Comment: Your addendum-idea with a static class containing static constant strings is already implemented :) I used the magic string in my example above out of simplicity.

Comment: Good :) . I'd also say that the way to choose your "key" for the factory differs on how this code is exposed. If it is hidden behind a facade and is kind of your own implementation detail then it doesn't really matter which option. However if it is somehow exposed for external use I'd prefer the `enum` or the `TRequest` options - a much clearer interface than `string` for others

Answer (score 3):

This is where constructor injection can REALLY shine. Look into dependency injection tools and employ one! It also checks your "Bonus" request.

Here's what your factory might look like with constructor injection:

```
public class DataFactory
{
    private Dictionary<string, IDataGenerator> generators;

    public DataFactory(IDataGenerator[] generatorReferences)
    {
        this.generators = generatorReferences
            .ToDictionary(k => k.name, v => v);
    }
    public IDataGenerator Create(string type)
    {
        IDataGenerator generator = null;
        this.generators.TryGetValue(type, out generator);
        return generator;
    }
}
```

Most DI software has the capability to automatically scan assemblies for implementations of a certain type (e.g. IDataGenerator) and register those with itself, when it constructs an instance of your DataFactory it'll automatically include them.

Comment: I'm using NInject. Simply having an Array of the interface in the constructor isn't enough, so I probably have to do some binding before. Now to make sure, that there is some simply way of doing this, without having to do extended reflection, which I could have done directly without NInject.

Comment: I have been using Ninject for years, an array will work fine. Just register all instances you have and it'll get injected. If I recall correctly the following are supported [], IEnumerable<T>, List<T>. Note that when injected via IEnumerable<T> it is lazy loaded and re-evaluated on each enumeration so be careful with that one.

Comment: Is there an easy and automatic way to register all instances which implement the interface / derive from the parent class? I'm not that good with NInject.

Comment: [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290353/ninject-bind-all-classes-implementing-the-same-interface)